# null pointer exception in list view?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-listview, contactscontract

hie,I am trying to retrieve contacts name and their type .I want to put them in list view ,but getting  null values at name and phone type array,as well as in list view.any help would be appreciable.thanks in advance.

```
package application.test;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;  
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
public final class TestActivity extends Activity {
String[] name;
String[] phoneType;
ListView lv;
String s[];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);        

   testGetContacts();

   lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        ArrayAdapter<String> sa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,s);
        lv.setAdapter(sa);

}//method

private void testGetContacts()  { 

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();    
    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.TYPE};     
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                projection, null, null, null);     

    if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) { 

        try {

            int indexID =  cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
            int indexName = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
             int indexPhoneType = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.TYPE);

          name=new String[cur.getCount()];

         phoneType=new String[cur.getCount()];


         while (cur.moveToNext()) {

               int  i=0;
               String id = cur.getString(indexID);    
     null-->    name[i] = cur.getString(indexName);  
     null-->     phoneType[i] =  cur.getString(indexPhoneType);       

              String temp="id="+id+"-name="+name[i]+"-phoneType="+phoneType[i];
              s[i]=temp;
              i++;
}//while
        }catch(Exception e){

e.printStackTrace();    
    }//catch
}//if
}//method}
}
```

**Logcat:**

```
11-08 15:21:45.250: WARN/System.err(1049): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-08 15:21:45.250: WARN/System.err(1049):     at application.test.TestActivity.testGetContacts(TestActivity.java:60)
11-08 15:21:45.270: WARN/System.err(1049):     at application.test.TestActivity.onCreate(TestActivity.java:23)
11-08 15:21:45.270: WARN/System.err(1049):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-08 15:21:45.270: WARN/System.err(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-08 15:21:45.270: WARN/System.err(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-08 15:21:45.270: WARN/System.err(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-08 15:21:45.270: WARN/System.err(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-08 15:21:45.279: WARN/System.err(1049):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 15:21:45.290: WARN/System.err(1049):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-08 15:21:45.290: WARN/System.err(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-08 15:21:45.290: WARN/System.err(1049):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 15:21:45.290: WARN/System.err(1049):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-08 15:21:45.290: WARN/System.err(1049):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-08 15:21:45.290: WARN/System.err(1049):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-08 15:21:45.300: WARN/System.err(1049):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 15:21:45.300: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1049): Shutting down VM
11-08 15:21:45.300: WARN/dalvikvm(1049): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{application.test/application.test.TestActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:49)
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:171)
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:125)
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at application.test.TestActivity.onCreate(TestActivity.java:26)
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-08 15:21:45.349: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1049):     ... 11 more
11-08 15:21:45.380: WARN/ActivityManager(58):   Force finishing activity application.test/.TestActivity
11-08 15:21:45.911: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{44f48960 application.test/.TestActivity}
11-08 15:21:47.029: DEBUG/SntpClient(58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
11-08 15:21:56.575: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{44f48960 application.test/.TestActivity}
```

Comment: is R.id.listview in your main.xml layout?

Comment: Please attach your stacktrace.

Comment: yeah I have that in my xml file..<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
        />
</LinearLayout>

Comment: what is stack trace.are you talking about log cat.

Comment: Check the integer value you got in indexName and indexphonetype correctly..may be these value be empty  so the value of cur.getString(indexName) value is null... please post your stacktrace to answer more..

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036850/getting-null-pointer-exception/8036921#8036921

Comment: on which line you are getting error give stackTrace.

Comment: indexname=1,indexphoneType=2,the values are not null

Comment: String s[] has never been initialized!

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
        String[] projection = new String[] { Data._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.TYPE}; 

      Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            projection, null, null, null);
```

EDIT: I just realized this is the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006716/how-to-get-contacts-type-in-android/8010698#8010698)...

You can try the following:

1) create a Class to represent 1 entry:

```
public class ContactsEntry {

String contactId;
String contactName;
String phoneType;
public String getContactId() {
    return contactId;
}
public void setContactId(String contactId) {
    this.contactId = contactId;
}
public String getContactName() {
    return contactName;
}
public void setContactName(String contactName) {
    this.contactName = contactName;
}
public String getPhoneType() {
    return phoneType;
}
public void setPhoneType(String phoneType) {
    this.phoneType = phoneType;
}


}
```

Than in your code:

```
              while (cur.moveToNext()) {

              String id = cur.getString(indexID);    
              String name = cur.getString(indexName);  
              String phoneType =  cur.getString(indexPhoneType);

              ContactsEntry entry = new ContactsEntry();
              entry.setContactId(id);
              entry.setContactName(name);
              entry.setPhoneType(phoneType);

               //// do some logging or whatever.


          }
```

Comment: I tried this but getting contact name in both the lines:Log.d("name",entry.getContactName());
Log.d("phoneType",entry.getPhoneType());

Comment: check your code if you use wrong set method, or wrong column index. I have tested this on my CallLogs phone database, and it get all data fields correctly.

Comment: I need to ask one thing that do indexId,indexName and indexPhoneType,need to have one value because they are getting values 0,1,2 respectively at initialization..

Comment: those are the column index numbers (they should have different values), contained in your cursor. Those numbers mean that, the column containing your IDs, has index 0, column containing names, has index 1 and so on.

Comment: any idea why setter and getter methods are running 20 times though I have only 10 contacts stored in my AVD.....

Answer (score 0):

move

```
int i = 0;
```

outside the loop (before it)

Comment: yeah,that was the error I suppose.getting the list now but application getting force close as soon i run out of contacts while dragging down the list

Answer (score 0):

Inititalize the String array name and phoneType as below

```
  String[] name=new String[5];//5 is size of String array
  String[] phoneType=new String[5]; //5 is size of String array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void testGetContacts() {

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.TYPE };
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, projection,
            null, null, null);

    if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {

        try {

            int indexID = cur
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
            int indexName = cur
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
            int indexPhoneType = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.TYPE);
            int count = cur.getCount();

            name = new String[count];
            phoneType = new String[count];
            s = new String[count];

            int i = 0;
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {

                String id = cur.getString(indexID);
                name[i] = cur.getString(indexName);
                phoneType[i] = cur.getString(indexPhoneType);
                String temp = "id=" + id + "-name=" + name[i]
                        + "-phoneType=" + phoneType[i];
                s[i] = temp;
                i = i + 1;
            }// while
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }// catch
    }// if
}// method}
```

1. you forgot to initialize String arrays
2. your count i isn't correct